# Allow one session per account

Tags: symfony

I search if there is a simple way to allow only one session per account with Symfony 3 ?

For the moment, I use the `PdoSessionHandler` to store sessions in database, and I've a listener on the `onSecurityInteractiveLogin` event. When the user is log-in, I set the sessionId in the User object, and persist it in database.

Now, I would like do it:
When a user is successfully login, I also inactivate the previous session, but how can I inactivate an other session ? In Symfony I can do it for the actual session, but not for an other...

Else, maybe I can process to a SQL request to delete the previous session, but then, the previous user loose all things stored in the session, I just want disconnect him.

An other way, is the inverse: say to the new user: "A session is actually open with your login, please disconnect from the other machine.", but if the user just close his browser (no click on logout) and comeback some seconds/minutes after with a remember me token, for exemple, he can't be log in... And must wait for several minutes.

If someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I've do it:

- In a SecurityInteractiveLoginListener: on successfull login, I add an entry with the session ID, in User record (database)
- On each request (KernelRequestEvent), I check is the sessionId of the user is the same than the Record in database, if yes it is the last connected user, else, an other session has been created, then I redirect the user on /logout, and I add a FlashMessage.

I've just a question about organization: I've 2 listeners, is it the best way ? Or I need to do a subscriber, and group 2 events in one file, because it's for the same functionnality.

In my security.yml

```
logout:
    path:   /logout
    target: /
    invalidate_session: false
```

The invalidate_session: false, permit to not destroy the session on logout, then I keep the session content, and I can add a flashbag when I forced the user logout.

My services declaration:

```
app.event_listener.security_interactive_login:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\SecurityInteractiveLoginListener
    arguments: ["@app.user_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login }

app.event_listener.kernel_request:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\KernelRequestListener
    arguments:
        - "@security.token_storage"
        - "@security.authorization_checker"
        - "@session"
        - "@router"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, priority: 0 }
```

The SecurityInteractiveLoginListener:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Utils\UserManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class SecurityInteractiveLoginListener
{
    private $userManager;

    public function __construct(UserManager $userManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->has('id'); // Just to fix a bug on Remember Me
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        // Set the session ID on user and save it in database
        $user->setSessionId($session->getId());
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }
}
```

The KernelRequestListener:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException;

class KernelRequestListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $authorizationChecker;
    private $session;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(
        TokenStorage $tokenStorage,
        AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker,
        Session $session,
        RouterInterface $router
    ) {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest() || !$this->isUserLoggedIn()) {
            return;
        }

        $sessionId = $this->session->getId();
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        // If the sessionId and the sessionId in database are equal: this is the latest connected user
        if ($sessionId === $user->getSessionId()) {
            return;
        }

        $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('danger', 'You have been logged out, because another person logged in whith your credentials.');
        $redirectUrl = $this->router->generate('logout');
        $response = new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }

    protected function isUserLoggedIn()
    {
        try {
            return $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED');
        } catch (AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException $exception) {
            // Ignoring this exception.
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I am trying to implement your solution, but I am having one problem. My symfony project doesn't find ["@app.user_manager"] in the services declaration, I am using FosUserBundle but I guess that I should be able to access to the Symfony's user manager, any suggestion?

Comment: In files that use UserManager, try to replace it by the FosUserBundle UserManager. In my case, I don't use FOS User, I've do it myself.

Comment: Sorry for bother you again, but maybe you can help me; I have configured that after my register I am logged automatically but using this event listener I am redirected to the login page (the session is destroyed) and I've to login again. I created an UserListener to override "onRegistrationCompleted", I added a session value there and I check that value onKernelRequest but it doesn't work. If you have any idea, I'd be grateful. Cheers!

Comment: @mpiot Thank You for your answer. I am not using FosUserBundle and I have the same problem mentioned above : cannot find user_manager -- use App\Utils\UserManager; where did you create this UserManager and what did you write inside it

Comment: @Mirachalak In past the UserManager that I was using just have some shortcut: create, update, update password, generate tokens. The update method in this case just flush, you totally can get the EntityManager and flush.

Comment: @mpiot thank you for your answer ! Can you share the code please ? So I should put @app.entity_manager instead of `arguments: ["@app.user_manager"]`  and `use App\EntityManager;` instead of use AppBundle\Utils\UserManager; ?

Comment: @mpiot I just need to know what to change and where. I am new to Symfony :)

Comment: I did this `$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` in onSecurityInteractiveLogin then finally I put this $entityManager->flush(); but still no update in the DB

Comment: @Mirachalak you can remove the arguments parts in services.yaml on actual Symfony versions. In the SecurityInteractiveLoginListener class just replace UserManager  per EntityManagerInterface, then use it to flush the user entity changes. For informations the project is here: https://github.com/gryc-inra/gryc-website

Comment: Thank you soooo much @mpiot !!! I used EntityManager instead of EntityManagerInterface  is it wrong ?

Comment: You're welcome. It works too, the EntityManagerInterface typehint give you the EntityManager services, just in Symfony it's recommended to use Interfaces for Services Autowiring.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this on a recent project. How I did it is:

1. On login, store a randomly generated token `$x` in both the session and the user record in the database.
2. In a request listener (`kernel.request`), compare the current login token
    `$user->getLoginToken()`, with the token in the session. If different,
3. Invalidate the session.
4. Set a new redirect response to an error page.
5. Call `$response->headers->clearCookie(....)` to clear out the session cookie and the remember me cookie. (I have the names of both of those set in my parameters and inject them into this request listener.)

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea, maybe I can store the `SessionId` in database on login, and compare the `$session->getId()` and the `$user->getSessionId()`, it do the same I think. It's actually my idea. Then, when I disconnect the user, I can add a flash message.

Comment: For the moment I've an idea, I can store the sessionId in database (on user), compare like you on each request if the sessionId == the user sessionId in database, if yes, I do nothing, else, I add a flashMessage and I redirect the user on /logout. Then it invalidate the session, and delete RememberMe cookie.