# Symfony allow One sessionn per station

Tags: symfony

I am trying to follow this post in order to restrict the username session to only one station  : [Allow one session per account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167640/allow-one-session-per-account)

I am getting the error of not existing user manager. So I should create this by myself? Of so how? I am not using FosUserBundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the accepted answer in the question you referenced, the `AppBundle\Utils\UserManager` is most likely just a custom implementation of the Doctrine `EntityManager` with methods to handle the tasks needed to update/persist the entity.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#updating-an-object